# Create custom converter for Azure Service Bus Output Binding in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am currently writing to the service bus like this:

```
[FunctionName("UpdateConfiguration")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] SampleConfiguration config,
   [ServiceBus("mytopic" , Connection = "ConnectionStrings:ServiceBusConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<Message> message,
        ILogger log)
{
   await message.AddAsync(CreateMessage(config));
   return new OkObjectResult(config);
}

public Message CreateMessage<TObject>(TObject body) where TObject : class, new()
{
   string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
   byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
   Message message = new (jsonBytes)
   {
      ContentType = "application/json",
      Label = "ConfigurationUpdated",
      To = Environment.MachineName
   };
   return message;
}
```

I want to simplify this by implementing a custom converter like described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings#3-add-converters). I already had a look in the source of [Azure Functions Service Bus Extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/tree/32f8df8a62c38cb5ae4333875d73d60f981045a3/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/Bindings), but everything seems to be internal so I am not sure if it is possible to add a custom binding where I can put my code for serializing the message.

Is there any way to add this custom converter:

```
public class ObjectToJsonMessageConverter<TObject> : IConverter<TObject, Message> where TObject: class, new()
{
    public Message Convert(TObject input)
    {
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
        byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
        Message message = new(jsonBytes)
        {
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Label = "ConfigurationUpdated",
            To = Environment.MachineName
        };
        return message;
    }
}
```

So I can do this?

```
[ServiceBus("mytopic" , Connection = "ConnectionStrings:ServiceBusConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<SampleConfiguration> configuration,
        ILogger log)
{
   await message.AddAsync(config);
   return new OkObjectResult(config);
}
```

The reason I want to do this because I do not want to inject a MessageFactory into each of my functions if there is a possibility to use a custom output binding. But I do not want to fork the complete Service Bus Binding to achieve this.

Comment: A custom converter seems a bit complicated to me, why don't you just use a factory pattern?

Comment: Because this means I need to inject a factory to all my functions (hundreds of functions). I like to keep the constructors and repeating code as small as possible and if there is a possibility using Output-Binding I would strongly prefer it as it is a native feature of Azure functions.

Comment: you cannot extend the existing binding. Best shot might be to fork the repo and write your own binding extension based on that. Note: this should be fine as long as you only need the output binding but it will not work reliably for triggers